# multiple locations with sharepoint and google maps

Tags: google-maps, sharepoint-2013

I'm using sharepoint 2013 to build a website for my business. We have three locations and i have a page that allows visitors to select each location from a search box and get information about that location on the page.
Everything works great so far but I'd also like to include a web part google map that displays each location as its searched for.
Is this possible?
If so can anyone give me an idea of how to code/include this on my page?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Bing maps which can be integrated very easily with SharePoint 2013. SharePoint 2013 has introduced a new column type named "Geolocation" . Geolocation field is not visible by default and an MSI package named SQLSysClrTypes.msi must be installed on every SharePoint front-end web server to view the geolocation field value or data in a list. You can generate the bing map key from here [Bing Maps Portal](https://www.bingmapsportal.com/)

You can refer this blog for more information on creating GeoLocation field :[Refer](http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-getting-started-with-the-new-geolocation-field-in-sharepoint-2013)

Below is a snap of code to create Geolocation Column

**Enabling Bing Map Key:**

```
 static private void SetBingMapsKey()
    {

        ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://sharepoint.com/");
        Web web = context.Web;
        web.AllProperties["BING_MAPS_KEY"] = "BBaCAAAAAAAAAAAA ";
        web.Update();
        context.ExecuteQuery();
    }
```

***Adding Geolocation Field:***

```
private static void AddGeolocationField()
    {

        ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://vc01cgr01cgsp03:39696/");
        List oList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Employees");
        oList.Fields.AddFieldAsXml("<Field Type='Geolocation' DisplayName='Home Town'/>", true, AddFieldOptions.AddToAllContentTypes);
        oList.Update();
        context.ExecuteQuery();
    }
```

If still you need to integrate this with Google Map.. Just explain your requirement in more detail. For e.g. how do you want to achieve this (Jquery/CLient Side or Server Side) ?, Are you using SharePoint Search or Custom List filter search ?

I hope this will help you :)